# TYPO3 9.5.3: Image rotation wrong at frontend

Tags: css, typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-9.x

I upgraded from an very old TYPO3 4.5 up to a 9.5.3 Version. My problem is, that portrait images have the wrong orientation. If I remove the width="{dimensions.width}" and height="{dimensions.height}", then it seems to be working, but the images are too large. At the filelist, the images are displayed correct. At the content type "images" they have the wrong rotation too, but can't rotate them.

```
<f:media class="image-embed-item" file="{file}" alt="{file.alternative}" title="{file.title}" width="{dimensions.width}" height="{dimensions.height}" />
```

[image: wrong rotation]

Comment: found a workaround for my problem: now I'm using GraphicsMagick instead of ImageMagick

Comment: could this be related? https://forge.typo3.org/issues/61655

Comment: maybe related to this one: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/69274

Comment: Now I'm getting the same bug at another typo3 (9.5.3) instance, but there I'm already using GraphicsMagick :/